# Check if a string/word exist in a file before writing to it

Tags: c, linux

Am having a little bit of a problem. I want to write to a file only if the same string/word am trying to write doesn't already exist. In my case its an IP address and port separated with ":". If I write manually to the file for example 193.*.*.*:80 and 193.*.*.*:22, it dictates them but still write to the file. Where is my mistake here :

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define INITIAL_ALLOC 2
#else
#define INITIAL_ALLOC 512
#endif


void BlockIP(char * s);
char *read_line(FILE *fin);
void *right_line(int p,char * s,int ssh,int http);



int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    //struct uci_context *uci;
    //uci = uci_init();

    char *ip = "193.2.2.1 193.2.6.6 193.168.1.1 193.5.5.5"
    //int uci_port = atoi(ucix_get_option(uci, "pack_mon", "manual_blocking", "port"));

    const char s[2] = " ";
    char *token;


    token = strtok(ip, s);

    while( token != NULL ) 
    {
        BlockIP(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, s);
    }

    return(0);
}


void BlockIP(char * s){
    int ssh = 22;
    int http = 80;
    char sshbuffer[2000]= "\0";
    char httpbuffer[2000]= "\0";

    char cmd2[2000] = "\0";
    char cmd[2000] = "\0";

    snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd),"iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp -s %s --dport 80 -j REJECT",s);
    snprintf(cmd2, sizeof(cmd2),"iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp -s %s --dport 22 -j REJECT",s);

    snprintf(sshbuffer, sizeof(sshbuffer),"%s:%d", s,ssh);
    snprintf(httpbuffer, sizeof(httpbuffer),"%s:%d", s,http);


    FILE *fp ,*ft;
    fp = popen(cmd, "r");

    pclose(fp);

    ft = popen(cmd2, "r");

    pclose(ft);

    FILE *fin;
    char *line;


    fin = fopen("/tmp/mymonlog", "r");

    if ( fin ) {
        while ( line = read_line(fin) ) {
            if (strstr(line, sshbuffer)){
                printf("Already exist %s\n",line);
            }else{
                right_line(1,s,ssh,http);

            }
            if(strstr(line, httpbuffer)){
                printf("Already exist %s\n",line);
            }else{
                right_line(2,s,ssh,http);
            }
            free(line);
        }
    }

    fclose(fin);
}

char *read_line(FILE *fin) {
    char *buffer;
    char *tmp;
    int read_chars = 0;
    int bufsize = INITIAL_ALLOC;
    char *line = malloc(bufsize);

    if ( !line ) {
        return NULL;
    }

    buffer = line;

    while ( fgets(buffer, bufsize - read_chars, fin) ) {
        read_chars = strlen(line);

        if ( line[read_chars - 1] == '\n' ) {
            line[read_chars - 1] = '\0';
            return line;
        }

        else {
            bufsize = 2 * bufsize;
            tmp = realloc(line, bufsize);
            if ( tmp ) {
                line = tmp;
                buffer = line + read_chars;
            }
            else {
                free(line);
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}


void *right_line(int p,char * s,int ssh,int http){

    FILE *pFile,*tFile;

    if(p == 1){
        pFile=fopen("/tmp/mymonlog", "a");


        if(pFile==NULL) {
            perror("Error opening file.");
        }else {
            fprintf(pFile, "%s:%d\n", s,ssh);
        }

        fclose(pFile);
    }else if(p == 2){
        tFile=fopen("/tmp/mymonlog", "a");

        if(tFile==NULL) {
            perror("Error opening file.");
        }
        else {
            fprintf(tFile, "%s:%d\n", s,http);
        }

        fclose(tFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: The very first line of main() has a type declaration that is not defined: 'uci_context *'.  Second line has an undefined function 'uci_init()'.  So far, it's not looking good for your question:(

Comment: uci_init() works just fine :D. i need it to get some data

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Both 'uci_init()' and  'ucix_get_option()' return pointers to data that is not freed in main().  While this is not necessarily a disaster, it is worrying - the lifetime of the data pointed to is in question.  You need to provide more code or, more likely do some more of your own debugging.  With what you provided, I cannot get past 'uci = uci_init();' looking potentially bad, (ie may return pointer to data local to the called function, and therefore UB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that it still writes to the file is that you check the file in a line-by-line manner.

Assume your file has:

```
193.2.2.1:22
193.2.2.1:80
```

and you want to check for `193.2.2.1:22` and `193.2.2.1:80`

First you read the line `193.2.2.1:22` and do

```
strstr("193.2.2.1:22", "193.2.2.1:22")
```

This is matched so it **will not** write to the file.

But then you do

```
strstr("193.2.2.1:22", "193.2.2.1:80")
```

This is **not** matched so it **will** write to the file.

Then you read the next line from the file which is `193.2.2.1:80` and do

```
strstr("193.2.2.1:80", "193.2.2.1:22")
```

This is **not** matched so it **will** write to the file.

Then you do

```
strstr("193.2.2.1:80", "193.2.2.1:80")
```

This is matched so it **will not** write to the file.

So now your file is:

```
193.2.2.1:22
193.2.2.1:80
193.2.2.1:80
193.2.2.1:22
```

**Conclusion:**

Don't do the check line-by-line. You need to check **all** lines in the file before you decide to write to the file.

A simple fix could be something like:

```
int save_ssh = 1;
int save_http = 1;
if ( fin ) {
    while ( line = read_line(fin) ) {
        if (strstr(line, sshbuffer)){
            printf("Already exist %s\n",line);
            save_ssh = 0;
        }
        if(strstr(line, httpbuffer)){
            printf("Already exist %s\n",line);
            save_http = 0;
        }
        free(line);
    }

    fclose(fin);

    if (save_ssh) right_line(1,s,ssh,http);
    if (save_http) right_line(2,s,ssh,http);
}
```

Comment: OMG this is brilliant. Thanks Alooooooot